# VSTO Word add-in Intercept Application Quit

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins

We have a third pary Word add-in that is closing word when any documents are closed.

This is forcing users to open Word again which takes a long time with the number of add-ins running.

I am hoping to prevent the application quit event from within our in house add-in.

A subscription has been made to the application quit event but I don't know where to go from here.

```
   ((Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event)this.Application).Quit += Application_Quit;

    void Application_Quit()
    {
        //Prevent Word from closing here
    }
```

Is it even possible to stop the event from running, if so how do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can disabled the problematic add-in from the Add-ins list.

The Word object model doesn't provide anything for that. The [Quit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194164(v=office.15).aspx) event doesn't allow to stop the action. Only the [DocumentBeforeClose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834271(v=office.15).aspx) event allows to cancel the action setting the Cancel parameter to true.

That's why I'd suggest contacting the add-in developer to change the code. I don't think that is the right idea to close the host application from the add-in.

Comment: Thanks, was hoping that wasn't the case but I think we will have to do as you suggest and contact the third party developer.  As the add-in is used for our document management system.